# how to join Dictionary<X,Y> and remove duplicate record

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<int, List<someclass>> = new Dictionary<int, List<someClass>>();`

The Class can be something like this

```
public class someclass
{ 
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string Alternativeaddress { get; set; }
    public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }
}
```

For example

The List inside the dictionary contain 2 row as bellow:

```
Output
CompanyName           address            Alternativeaddress      CompanyNumber
AAAA                  11 Mainden Street  NULL                    3243-A
AAAA                  NULL               12 Maiden Street        3243-A
```

Is That anyway to make Join record 1 and 2 as 1 record in the dictionary by using LINQ or any method ? and it will remove the duplicated or JOINED record

```
Output
CompanyName           address            Alternativeaddress      CompanyNumber
AAAA                  11 Mainden Street  12 Maiden Street        3243-A
```

Company with both address will be remain and The key is auto increment number which make every row unique .

The Comparer That i would like to use will be CompanyNumber and CompanyName , because I found that this 2 value will not be null. and also it is the only way to identify they are the same.

Comment: What do you want to have happen if one record has both an address and a alternativeaddress, and the other only has an address? How do you resolve conflicts?

Comment: What does the `int` key of the dictionary represent? Should only values with the same key be joined?

Comment: The key is auto increment number

Comment: Just a side note, but if `CompanyNumber` is a unique identifier, wouldn't it make more sense to use that as your dictionary key, instead of another arbitrary number?

Comment: @abccba - If the key is an autoincrement number, why not just use a `List`?

Answer (score 5):

This should be possible using [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx), [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) and the [`null coalesce operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

---

I added a ctor to your `someclass` for convenience:

```
public class someclass
{ 
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string Alternativeaddress { get; set; }
    public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }
    public someclass(string name, string address, string address2, string number)
    {
        this.CompanyName=name;
        this.address=address;
        this.Alternativeaddress=address2;
        this.CompanyNumber=number;
    }
}
```

---

So, given a list of `someclass`, like this:

```
var a = new someclass("AAAA", "11 Mainden Street", null, "3243-A");
var b = new someclass("AAAA", null, "11 Mainden Street", "3243-A");

var c = new someclass("BBBB", null, null, "hooray");
var d = new someclass("BBBB", "something", null, "hooray");
var e = new someclass("BBBB", null, "foobar", "hooray");

var list = new List<someclass>() {a, b, c, d, e};
```

you could use a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<someclass> MergeList(IEnumerable<someclass> list)
{
    // use 'GroupBy' for grouping, obv.
    foreach(var g in list.GroupBy(l => Tuple.Create(l.CompanyName, l.CompanyNumber)))
    {
        // use 'Select', 'Aggregate' and '??' to find the first non-empty string for each property
        var adress = g.Select(x => x.address).Aggregate((x, y) => x ?? y);
        var alternative = g.Select(x => x.Alternativeaddress).Aggregate((x, y) => x ?? y);
        // return a new 'someclass'
        yield return new someclass(g.Key.Item1, adress, alternative, g.Key.Item2);  
    }
}
```

to constuct a new `someclass` for each group of `CompanyName`/`CompanyNumber`:

```
var merged = MergeList(list);
```

---

Result:

```
 CompanyName | address            | Alternativeaddress | CompanyNumber   
-------------+--------------------+--------------------|----------------  
 AAAA        | 11 Mainden Street  | 11 Mainden Street  | 3243-A   
 BBBB        | something          | foobar             | hooray
```

---

Note that this creates a new collection rather than changing the original `List` in-place, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: Very slick, and I actually like that the code creates a new list, leaving the old intact, so it would work with immutable collections.

Comment: LOL.  Don't tell the functional programmers.